# OpenCV: Merging fitted shapes

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

If I'm using OpenCV (Python) and fit two shapes, like so:

```
a = cv2.fitEllipse(contours)
b = cv2.minAreaRect(contours)
```

Both `a` and `b` are represented as `Box2D` objects, which look something like:

```
center: (x, y)
size: (width, height)
rotation: angle
```

`a` and `b` are often going to be fairly similar, but not exact due to different fit methods. How can I find the shape (ellipse) that is the "average" of `a` and `b`? That is, the ellipse that is the best fit between `a` and `b`?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve IMO. Consider adding an example image with the results `a` and `b` and a drawing of what the desired result should look like in that specific case.

Comment: Can you provide some sample values for `a` and `b`, along with expected output?

Comment: Can you describe/elaborate what you mean by "average" and "best fit", is it by area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of 'average' can be ambiguous and gives you different solutions. If this does not matter too much to you as you just want to average the shape in any way, below is a simple solution of how to average two rectangles:

Denote the two rectangles `(a1, a2, a3, a4)` and `(b1, b2, b3, b4)`. Let's say we want to find rectangle `(x1, x2, x3, x4)` minimize

[image: <code>sum |xi - ai|^2 + sum |xi - bi|^2</code>]

A rectangle is parameterized as

[image: <code>x_i = R q_i + c</code>]

where `R` is a 2D rotation matrix and `q_i` is one of [image: +-w, +-h] with `w` and `h` unknown rectangle size. `p` is the unknown rectangle center.

The overall formulation forms a quadratic programming problem, with unknowns `w, h, R, p` and quadratic constraints `R` is a rotation matrix.